# Android Save Log Or Bug Tracking

Tags: android, logging, tracking

I have developed application in Android and submit to client for testing feature now at that time error are generated now I want to track that error. I have use android `Log.e(string,string)` method for logging. Is it save any where in android device I can check that bug. Or have any bug tracking solution for android that give me log of application.

Comment: Yes, there is a log collector app which you can install in your device which will keep track of the log. But I don't remember the name of that log app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use acra for that : http://code.google.com/p/acra/
It's really easy to use and you can include almost anything you want in your crash reports.